# How to find files with number in extension in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, find

I want to find files having date in their extension.
In a folder having following files:

```
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0000
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0341
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0341.tz
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0355
```

I only want to find

```
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0000
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0341
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0355
```

**Edit:** Also if second block is optional. e.g.

```
access.log.20180124
access.log.20180125
```

I tried following:

```
find . * | grep "\*\.[0-9]{8}\.\*"
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '*\.[0-9+]\.[0-9+]'
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '*\.[0-9+]\.*'
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\.[0-9+]\.*'
find . -regextype sed -regex "*.{[0-9]+\.[0-9]+}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -regex '.*\.[0-9]+'
```

- Use `.*` rather than `*` at the front to match any prefix.
- `+` needs to be outside the square brackets.
- `-regextype` isn't necessary.

If you `extglob` is enabled then you can do this directly in the shell:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls *.+([0-9])
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0000  jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0341  jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0355
```

If you want a recursive search, turn on `globstar` as well:

```
$ shopt -s extglob globstar
$ ls **/*.+([0-9])
jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0000  jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0341  jvm-app-0.log.20180124.0355
```

Comment: pheww works.. Can you please also suggest regex if number block after second dot is optional

Comment: See my updated answer. All you need to do is match one number block instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

You are close, you may use this `find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$'
```

Above `find` will require `gnu find`. To make it work on other `find` versions such as `BSD` use:

```
find . -regex '.*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$'
```

---

If you are using `bash` you may also use `extglob` with `globstar` and **avoid** `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob

printf '%s\n' **/*.+([0-9])
```